# Passing data/strings from Maven to Java/JUnit app?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, junit, parameters

I have Eclipse and also installed manually Maven on win7-64 machine.
I need to be able to pass data to the Java and Java/JUnit test app.
It works in the console. F.e. if I do :

```
mvn -Dvar1=blah1 -Dvar2=blah2 test
```

I can read the data in the Java/Junit code like this :

```
String var1 = System.getPropertiy("var1")
String var2 = System.getPropertiy("var2")
```

But if I do "maven  test" with the Eclipse "internal" maven (m2e) and ofcourse specify "-Dvar1=blah1 -Dvar2=blah2" in VM-properties in the Run-as box, the values are "null" when I try to print them.

Can you point me to what to look for, so I can solve this problem.
(It has to work in both environments).

Btw. I don't add anything to pom.xml to make this work in the first case.
I'm saying this because the Q/A I see that closely resemble my problem, seems to imply I have to add something to pom.xml!!

My more broad question is passing small configuration tokens of data via this properties-mechanism the best-practice, correct method to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure, I understood your question correctly. I'm speculating that you are having trouble in passing params for 'maven test' in eclipse.

If so, Run As --> Run Configurations --> Create a new maven configuration from 'Maven Build' on left pane

In 'Main' tab, choose your project --> Then use 'Add' button below to add parameters. Then you will be able to read those params as system properties in program

[image]

Comment: thanks, I will try that. I was setting the params in the JRE-tab under VM options.

Comment: You can also use String var1 = System.getProperty("var1","blah1") to set blah1 as the default value for var1